# Using DB2, "statement.executeQuery()" throws SqlEception only in my system

Tags: db2, websphere-6.1

```
//Class UserProfileDBUtil.java

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement statment = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        String sqlString = "select count(*) from "+AGENCY_SCHEMA_NAME+".AGENCY         WHERE AGENCYCODE= ? and ENABLEDFLAG = ?";
        conn = JDBCUtils.getConnection(JDBCUtils.WP_ODS);
        statment = conn.prepareStatement(sqlString);
        statment.setString(1, agencyCode.toUpperCase());
        statment.setString(2, "Y");
        rs =statment.executeQuery();  // SQL Error Line 42
        while(rs.next())
        {
            if(rs.getInt(1) > 0 )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        log.error("Agency for agency code "+agencyCode+" is not available or not active");
    }
```

LOG :

com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -401, SQLSTATE: 42818, SQLERRMC: =
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.sf.e(sf.java:1680)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.sf.a(sf.java:1239)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.jb.h(jb.java:139)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.jb.a(jb.java:43)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.w.a(w.java:30)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.cc.g(cc.java:161)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.sf.n(sf.java:1219)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.tf.gb(tf.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.tf.d(tf.java:2294)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.tf.X(tf.java:508)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.tf.executeQuery(tf.java:491)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:559)
    at UserProfileDBUtil.isAgencyActive(UserProfileDBUtil.java:42)

Comment: Please Note : Exception is throwing only on my system. Using webspere app server 6.1. Connection and statement are both not null. Code working perfectly on other systems. JDK : websphere jdk 6.1

Comment: On different systems, you could well be using different versions of the DB2 JDBC driver, which sometimes means different ways of mapping between Java types and SQL column types. Check your JDBC driver version levels, and also post the SQL column types here.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is a `-401`, [which means](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00401n.html):

> The data types of the operands for the operation `operator` are not
>   compatible or comparable.

I would check and make sure that the parameters you're passing in are using the right data types. If you catch the exception, you should be able to use the exceptions `Message` property to see what the `operator` is.  [See here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzaha/exceptions.htm) for an example.

Comment: Hi..I just found if i try preparedstmt.setString(1,locale) then error comes. If i set the locale in query as "where locale = "+locale+" , it works fine. So issue in in setString method and in any query with same datatype